# Cannot handle tap on UIBarButtonItem on the right side

Tags: uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I cannot handle tap on UIBarButtonItem on the right side.

```
hamburgerView = HamburgerIcon()
hamburgerView.userInteractionEnabled = true
hamburgerView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hamburgerIconClicked)))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: hamburgerView)
```

But when I'm using this button on the left side, all works well.

```
hamburgerView = HamburgerIcon()
hamburgerView.userInteractionEnabled = true
hamburgerView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hamburgerIconClicked)))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: hamburgerView)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting frame for `hamburgerView` has solved the issue.

`hamburgerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0)`

Why there is different between left and right side I don't know.